# How to write $ip value to file in windbg by windbg command

Tags: windbg

I want to write a variable value into a file using windbg.
for example, if a breakpoint matches, how to write the `$ip` value in to a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read that registry value you enter the command:

[`r ip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554663(v=vs.85).aspx)

you can either write the contents of the window to text using the GUI:

> Edit->Write Window Text To File'

Or use [`logopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

An example complete command from my windbg sessions looks like the following:

```
0:392> r ip
ip=590
0:392> .logopen c:\data\ip.txt
Opened log file 'c:\data\ip.txt'
0:392> .echo ip register val:; r ip
ip register val:
ip=590
0:392> .logclose
Closing open log file c:\data\ip.txt
```

So here I open a log file using `.logopen` then issue an [`.echo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562940(v=vs.85).aspx) command (optional really but it allows you to write the output some comments), and then display the `$ip` register value using `r ip`, and finally close the log `.logclose`.

This produces a log with the following contents:

```
Opened log file 'c:\data\ip.txt'
0:392> .echo ip register val:; r ip
ip register val:
ip=590
0:392> .logclose
Closing open log file c:\data\ip.txt
```

So the complete thing would be something like:

```
bp myll!myfunc ".logopen c:\folder\ip.txt; .echo ip register value:; r ip; .logclose"
```

Of course substitute the bp params and log location for your needs.

As ThomasW has pointed out, this will overwrite the log every time the breakpoint is hit so if this behaviour is undesirable then use [`.logappend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563986(v=vs.85).aspx) instead

Comment: Wouldn't `.logopen` overwrite the file every time? You could use it with the `/t` switch to add the time or use `.logappend` instead.

Comment: If you don't like the number format, you can also use `.printf "%p\n",@ip;` or similar instead of `r ip`.

Comment: @ThomasW. that's true but what the OP really wants has not been defined but it's a fair point